# CSS HTML Cant click on links

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, z-index

I have this page here: http://artendijen.com/product/animals-stream/ and there are links on the right side, however I can't click on them...does anyone know why?

Left Side:

```
<nav class="woocommerce-breadcrumb" itemprop="breadcrumb"><a class="home" href="http://artendijen.com">Home</a> / <a class="home" href="/shop">Gallery &amp; Shopping</a> / <a href="http://artendijen.com/product-category/small/#108">Small</a> / Animals by the Stream</nav>
```

Right Side:

```
<ul style="float:right;" class="shoppingBread"><li><a href="/product-category/prints-notecards">Prints &amp; Notecards</a></li><li><a href="/product-category/background-information">Background Information</a></li><li><a href="/cart">Cart</a></li></ul>`
```

CSS for left side:

```
.woocommerce .woocommerce-breadcrumb, .woocommerce-page .woocommerce-breadcrumb {
    float: left;
    z-index: 99999;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: .92em;
    color: #777;
}
```

CSS for right side is just float right, but here is the CSS for the list items on the right side:

```
.shoppingBread li {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The list:

```
<ul style="float:right;" class="shoppingBread"><li><a href="/product-category/prints-notecards">Prints &amp; Notecards</a></li><li><a href="/product-category/background-information">Background Information</a></li></ul>
```

is being covered by a div that comes after it. Add the following CSS to your list and it will be clickable:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

OR, you can just clear the div that comes after the list:

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="product-108" class="post-108 product type-product status-publish hentry instock">
```

by adding `clear: both;`

Comment: Or remove `float:right`, that will work, as they are aligned with `text-align:right`.

Comment: @JoshC - Was updating my answer to give a second solution which clears the floated list which is pretty much the same as what you just suggested ;)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following from your css:

```
.woocommerce div.product, .woocommerce-page div.product, .woocommerce #content div.product, .woocommerce-page #content div.product {

    position: relative;  ///Remove this 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.woocommerce div.product, .woocommerce-page div.product, .woocommerce #content div.product, .woocommerce-page #content div.product {
margin-bottom: 0;
position: relative;
}
```

Remove `position: relative;` and it will work. It doesn't seem to be affecting the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<header>` element is overlapping the links so the links can't be hovered over or clicked upon:

[image]

Take a look at restructuring your markup or using `[z-index][2]` to get the element containing the links above the `<header>`.

You can also remove position: relative from this line in your CSS, although that may have other unintended knock-on effects:

```
.woocommerce div.product, .woocommerce-page div.product, .woocommerce #content div.product, .woocommerce-page #content div.product
```